# How to recover deleted project admins and users from the TFS organizations in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

It is accidental deletion of System admins from Azure DevOps TFS Project.
Is there any way to recover deleted project admins and users from the Project of TFS organizations in Azure DevOps?
way to recover deleted project admins and users from the Project of TFS organizations in Azure DevOps?

Comment: Are you using Azure DevOps Services (organization) or Azure DevOps Server (project collection)? If using Azure DevOps Server, what is the version?